# SCSS: pseudo-class :first-of-type affects all types

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I would like to ask for your help regarding :first-of-type pseudo-class. Please, can you check the example of simplified code bellow i'm using - :first-of-type affects all types or nothing.

HTML:

```
<div id='nav'>
  <div class='row'> 

    <div class='cell'>
      <strong>Subject 1</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='cell'>
      <strong>Subject 2</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>  

  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#nav{
  @extend %filter_full_size;

  strong{
    color: $color_blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;

    &:first-of-type{
      &:after{
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: $color_blue;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to use :first-of-type for parent element with class 'cell' but it didn't work at all.

```
#nav{
  @extend %filter_full_size;
  
  .cell{
    strong{
      ......
    }

  &:first-of-type{ 
    strong{ 
      &:after{
        ......
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.
P.

Comment: Each of those `strong` ARE `first-of-type` in it's respective parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt picked up every strong element since they were all the first children of their respective parent elements.

I couldn't at first glance see anything wrong with your second attempt, where you had selected the strong element that was a child of the first .cell element. However, we haven't seen the full code so maybe there is something wrong in that?

I 'translated' the SCSS to CSS to check and this is the result I saw:
[image]

If this is what you wanted here is the snippet:

```css
#nav .cell strong{
    color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}

 #nav .cell:first-of-type strong::after{
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: blue;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id='nav'>
  <div class='row'> 

    <div class='cell'>
      <strong>Subject 1</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='cell'>
      <strong>Subject 2</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>  

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. There was a typo that I removed unaware during simplifying the code and posting.